# Web app that creates growl notifications for sports scores?

Tags: notifications, mac, events

I am interested in finding a web app that will monitor the score of a sports game and send a growl alert to my computer when the score changes or when the game is over.  Does anyone know if such a web app exists or how to create such growl alerts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my solution on this one would be to find an RSS feed of the scores I was interested in, then use something like RSS Growler or OmniGrowl for the notification.

Comment: OmniGrowl is awesome, thanks so much!